# Using Firestore: How to prevent a malicious ip from sending too many requests?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, request, ip

Because I didn't see any other posts that specifically asked this question phrased in this way, I thought I might ask.

An example of "too many requests" might be a malicious user altering the client-side code so that it creates a new user (stored in Firecloud) as frequently as possible.

Comment: Did you already see [How do I implement a write rate limit in Cloud Firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules)

Comment: Haha, I missed this when I did my initial search.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Like Frank van Puffelen pointed out, this has already been answered and is found here: [How do I implement a write rate limit in Cloud Firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules)

The keywords used in this post are different than the one used in the post linked above, so I feel like it's worth it to keep this post around just in case someone gets here via a Google search using these keywords.