# How to limit the writes in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, spam

I want  to allow user to post a blog after every 3 hours of the last post.I dont want my daily limit of free plan to be finished up by spams of writes in firestore. How should I start. I am using redux, react, firestore. The objective is to how can I initiate my code and Logic

Comment: When storing a blog to Firestore, why not include the date and time that it was stored? Then, when storing a blog, first check to see if the user has any that were posted within the last 3 hours... And if there are none, allow them to post!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the firestore rules to ensure 100% safety.
Puf has a great answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules).

If you allow writes to specific users I would recommend to save with a firebase function under `users/writetimes/{userUid}` the time he createt the last post and when writing again check if the users last `timestamp` is more than 3h ago.

Something like this:

```js
match /users/{document=**} {
  allow create: if isCalm();
  function isCalm() {
    return request.time > get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/writetimes/$(request.auth.uid)).data.timestamp + duration.value(3, 'h');
  }
}
```