# Avoiding spam requests in firebase aka debouncing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

So things are going well in my development so far! But the more I think about how I'll deal with costs of reads/writes the more I imagine someone with ill-intentions spamming a button to send requests. I also have a screen that if a request fails, it just sends an alert but other than that the screen remains untouched and a person could replay the request very easily.

Before I start thinking of ways to avoid this.. I'm wondering if I'll be re-inventing the wheel here.. any working strategies for this already?

Comment: For Firestore you can implement something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement a write rate limit in Cloud Firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules)