# How to implement spam control in firebase firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I am trying to make a spam control so users can't create that many requests to my database. For now, I have only implemented timeout on the frontend, but who knows how long it will take to bypass... I search pretty much everywhere and didn't find anything... does anyone here know?

[image: My firebase rules code]

Comment: So one can send message every 5 seconds only?

Comment: no, the function canSendMessage does NOT work...

Comment: Do you have a createdAt field in the document? Have you tested these rules in the playground?

Comment: I have tested it. With and without that function. In both cases I could spam the database with requests to create new document

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The rules you shared seem similar to the ones from my answer on [How do I implement a write rate limit in Cloud Firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487579/209103) What isn't working about these rules for you? Can you show the code of how you're testing them?