# Update document at least after a day Firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following problem: client side I create a document containing the timestamp:

```js
  db.collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .set({
    .....
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  })
```

After that I update it via:

```js
  db.collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .update({
    .....
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  })
```

In Firestore rules I have done:

```js
match /users/{userId}{
  allow create: .......
  allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId && 
                (
                   (request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['name', 'description', 'timestamp'])
                      && (request.resource.data.name != resource.data.name || request.resource.data.description != resource.data.description)
                      && request.resource.data.name is string && request.resource.data.name.matches(".*<.*") == false
                      && request.resource.data.description is string && request.resource.data.description.matches(".*<.*") == false
                      && request.resource.data.timestamp>resource.data.timestamp
                 )
```

The problem is on the last line:

```js
request.resource.data.timestamp>resource.data.timestamp
```

I would like not only the current timestamp to be greater than the timestamp saved in the document, but also for there to be a difference of at least one day, so as to prevent a user from continuously editing a document. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Also see [How do I implement a write rate limit in Cloud Firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.resource.data.timestamp` does not ensure that user has used `serverTimestamp()` and can by any timestamp. If you want to compare a the `timestamp` field with current time, it's best to use `request.time`. Try the following rule:

```
allow update: if request.time - resource.data.timestamp > duration.value(1, 'd') && ...other_conditions;
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/) to learn more about [`rules.timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.duration_#.value) and [`rules.duration`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.duration_#.value).

Comment: I don't think OP has a requirement for the `timestamp` value to be *now*, as long as it's at least one day after its current value. So I actually recommend checking `request.resource.data.timestamp - resource.data.timestamp > duration.value(1, 'd')`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I thought it might prevent user from passing a future timestamp (even if it's been only 1 hour since last update) in request body for the rule to pass.

Comment: I agree it's a useful check, but the question seems to be about the date diff. You cover that too (hence my upvote), I just wanted to point out that the comparison to `request.time` is not strictly needed (and I'd typically separate that check - shown in my answer to the question I linked above).

Comment: thank you both , that was what I was looking for. And thanks also for the advice about the request.time