# Counter Based Free-Trial in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am building a React App that will be subscription based and it will be using Stripe.
Briefly, it saves prompts (text) with a label

The problem I am facing is that I want to give the user 5 free saves and then ask him to subscribe.
Can anyone help me know what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

I thought of creating a counter in the user document and decrement it whenever a prompt is added.
But the question is, should I do this in the client side after each save request or should I make an even-based cloud function that is triggered on document addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitive *should* here: you can do this either with only client-side code and security rules, or with a Cloud Function.

For an example of how to limit writes from a specific client, have a look at my answer here: [How do I implement a write rate limit in Cloud Firestore security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487578/how-do-i-implement-a-write-rate-limit-in-cloud-firestore-security-rules) You'll have to modify it to your use-case, but that should be easier than starting from scratch.

Comment: I would rather go for the client side one because I want to avoid cloud functions cold starts.

Comment: Though I have one more question please: Is it save to do such this on the client side? is there a possibility that a user could tweak the code and disable the decrement request that is being sent after each save request?

Comment: If you read the answer I linked, it shows how to implement security rules that will reject such code tweaks.